# texlive 2011 / ubuntu 12.04 and TeX Live Backports PPA

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu

I've installed Texlive 2011 in Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits) following this tuto :
http://starlinq.livejournal.com/2542.html

I've changed the PATH and so on in the ~/.profil file.

But after that, I've enabled the TeX Live Backports PPA and downloaded its Texlive packages, without having uninstalled the first TexLive 2011 nor changed the PATH.

As a result, I don't know which Texlive version I use, and what I have to do to "clean" my installation.
Could you help me ?!

A "latex --v" command in a terminal answered:

> pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
>   kpathsea version 6.0.1
>   Copyright 2011 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
>   covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
>   the Lesser GNU General Public License.
>   For more information about these matters, see the file
>   named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
>   Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
>   Compiled with libpng 1.5.2; using libpng 1.5.2
>   Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
>   Compiled with xpdf version 3.02pl5

In Synaptic, all the texlive packages appear to come from the ppa (2012.20120529-1~precise1)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps `kpsewhich` will help..?  E.g.: `kpsewhich -show-path latex`

Comment: @jon Are you meaning `which latex`?

Comment: @egreg -- Won't that just say something like `/usr/bin/latex`?  I thought maybe `-show-path` or `kpsewhich -var-value TEXINPUTS` might give a sense of which texmf 'base' Ratoune2008's system searches.  But I've never double installed like this, so I'm not sure if `kpsewhich` will return output that can help him make the determination he wants....

Comment: @jon Usually the "vanilla" installation of TeX Live is done without putting the binaries (or aliases thereof) in `/usr/bin/`, so `which latex` might shed light. Probably `kpsewhich plain.tex` could give more information. What's certain is that `kpsewhich -show-path latex` doesn't tell anything apart from ``Ignoring unknown file type `latex'``

Comment: @egreg -- `kpsewhich -show-path latex` produces output on my machine: Ubuntu 11.10, with TeX Live installed from the repositories (with many packages updated from CTAN, but otherwise a default install).  `kpsewhich plain.tex` suggests where the texmf tree is for me, too, but not any better than, say `kpsewhich article.cls` --- unless I'm missing something.  Also, won't the PPA install TeX Live things the same way as before (thereby putting a link to `/usr/bin/pdftex` at `/usr/bin/latex`)?

Comment: Right, kpsewhich -show-path latex doesn't say nothing apart from Ignoring unknown file type `latex'. But kpsewhich plain.tex answers a /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/plain.tex
path. I don't know whether it can help ? Anyway, thanks a lot for your first comments...

Comment: Why did you mixup two TeXLive installations? _Either_ use some version from ubuntu _or_ the one from TeXLive. Depending on _how_ you installed TeXLive, it should be enough to `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2011`.
And of course you can simply compare your current system with the last backup prior to installing TeXLive.

Comment: Weell, both your comment and @egreg's make it clear that things have changed in 12.04 regarding TeX Live.  But it also sounds like both the repository (`apt`) version of TeX Live and the backported version install in the same place --- so my guess is that you don't really have a double system, especially since 12.04 seems to use TL 2009 by default and you only have `/usr/local/texlive/2011/` (or do you have `/usr/local/texlive/2009`?).  If there is only the one, then you can of course do `sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove`.  Can you do `latex small2e` in a terminal?

Comment: @Ratoune2008 The output of `kpsewhich plain.tex` means that you're using the "vanilla" TeX Live. Be sure that `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/<arch>` is before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` variable. If you want to use the PPA provided distribution, then change `PATH` not to refer to that directory.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I've done it before thinking it, as I'm a fool ;-). In fact, I discovered the ppa backports some minutes after having installed the "vanilla" version... Thanks to all for your help, I think I got it: I had only the '/usr/local/texlive/2011/' directory (not a '.../2009/' one). I've undone the PATH changes, and made a 'sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove'. Then, when I do a 'latex --v' in a terminal, I get a 'This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled'. Thanks to all !